# WhatsApp like Emoticon Icon set

Tags: icons, emoticons

I'm not sure this question fits right with guideline mentioned in stack overflow [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

I what to have a goole hangout/WhatsApp like emoticon set for a web application.

So far I'm using [jQuery CSS Emoticons](http://os.alfajango.com/css-emoticons/) which does not use any images for smilies.

Icon finder.com does not yield any icon sets.

Is there any freely available icon set similar to http://www.skype-emoticons.com/ or whatsapp set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A completely free and open set of emoji.

https://github.com/Genshin/PhantomOpenEmoji
(check [licence here](https://github.com/Genshin/PhantomOpenEmoji/blob/master/LICENSE.md) )

Another set

https://github.com/github/gemoji
(check [licence here](https://github.com/github/gemoji/blob/master/LICENSE) )